# Azure B2C Single Sign On Can't Set SMS Sender ID

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In Azure you can setup your own SMS API to a 3rd party so you can set the Sender Id of your text messages to your companies own dedicated numbers.

Does anyone know how you can do this with Azure AD B2C?

Need to set it to an Australian Sender ID

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Currently, this isn't supported, but you can vote for this feature at [Change MFA sender phone number and content](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20539867-change-mfa-sender-phone-number-and-content).